# download a folder from an FTP server using flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, ftp, download

I am building an application which runs on a user's local machine, but I want it to be able to update itself by downloading files from an FTP server. Can anyone recommend a good starting point for accomplishing this? An actionscript class or a utility / plugin or something? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Adobe AIR 1.5 * Updating AIR applications](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappsflex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ff2.html#WS9CD40F06-4DD7-4230-B56A-88AA27541A1E).  It probably doesn't handle FTP-based sources (HTTP: *yes*), but it is supposed to address the general problem you're facing.  Quote:

> [...]
>
> **Using the update framework**
>
> Managing updates of applications can
>   be complicated. The update framework
>   for AdobeAIR applications **provides
>   APIs to assist developers in providing
>   good update capabilities in AIR
>   *applications***. The functionality in the
>   AIR update framework assists
>   developers in the following:
>
> - Periodically checking for updates based on an interval or at the
>     request of the user
> - Downloading AIR files (updates) from a web source
> - Alerting the user on the first run of the newly installed version
> - Confirming that the user wants to check for updates
> - Displaying information on the new update version to the user
> - Displaying download progress and error information to the user
>
> [...]

Comment: Hey - this isn't quite what I'm looking for - I think this deals more with updating AIR itself. I might have a lead in this, though: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/FileReference.html. Only problem is that it only downloads individual files, not entire directories.

Comment: @mheavers You're mistaken. What my answer refers to purports to deal with updating AIR **applications**, and not the AIR runtime itself.  See the part I just highlighted.

Comment: just a followup - you were right - this is really the only way to go that I've found. Really didn't want to have to get involved with AIR / Flex but I think that's my only option. There is product out there called mProjector which is supposed to have a class to accomplish this, but the developers are having problems with it on various OS / Flash configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for:

http://projects.maliboo.pl/FlexFTP/

Comment: This looks awesome, but I don't think I'm nearly smart enough to figure it out. I have never done anything in Flex - just Flash. How would I integrate this into a flash project?

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to dig into that code yourself. I'm not familiar with it. It does look like an FTP library.